# PL/SQL oracle managing access control

Tags: oracle, security, syntax-error, access-control

I'm trying to solve a stored procedure in oracle based on this statement...
Access control on oracle database where

a)  Each user is allowed to access the system within certain time limit of a day. For example, user1 is allowed to access the system from 8 am to 4 pm, while user2 is allowed to access the system from 3 pm to 11 pm.

b)  For every user, accounts will be locked upon three logon failures.

c)  For every user, idle session will be terminated after 10 minutes.

d)  Highly privileged users are allowed to have a maximum of two concurrent sessions at one time, while other users are allowed to have one concurrent session only.

I manage to answer b,c,d question using profile. Then I alter the user to the profile. The stored procedure keep give me compilation error.   THANKS IN ADVANCE
Here are my work

```
    create role roleUser;
    grant create session to roleUser;
    grant select on staff_data to roleUser;  
    create user user1 identified by abc123;
    create user user2 identified by abc123;
    --common user privilege 
    create profile userProfile limit
    FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3
    IDLE_TIME 10
    SESSIONS_PER_USER 1


    --high user  privilege
    create profile userHighProfile limit
    FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3
    IDLE_TIME 10
    SESSIONS_PER_USER 2

    alter user user1 profile userProfile;
    alter user user2 profile userHighProfile;
    grant roleUser to user1,user2;


    show error;
    create or replace trigger limit_logon 
    after logon on database
    begin
    if to_char(sysdate,'HH24') between 8 and 16 then
    set roleUser to user1;
    elsif to_char(sysdate,'HH24') between 15 and 23 then
    set roleUser to user2;
    else
    revoke roleUser  from user1;
    revoke roleUser from user2;
    end if;
    end;
```

Comment: `The stored procedure keep give me compilation error.` It would be nice if you post that error messages too.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you'd have a table containing ranges of times in which a user is allowed to login, and when a user logs in your logon trigger would check the current time against the range(s) for the user. Create a procedure or function to encapsulate the logic, and let it raise an error if the user is not allowed to logon at that time.

Of course this doesn't log the user out at the end of the window.

I have a feeling that what you also need here is a DBMS_Scheduler job that runs periodically to check that all sessions' users are allowed to be logged in at that time, so that users' sessions can be killed if they stay logged in past their window.

Answer (score 0):

`set roleUser to user1;` must be `execute immediate 'grant roleUser to user1';`

`revoke roleUser  from user1;` must be `execute immediate 'revoke roleUser  from user1';`

However, it will not work as desired because GRANT/REVOKE ROLE is executed **after** logon, thus it does not affect the current session, the user first would have to logoff and logon again.

Instead of grant and revoke a role, you can enable and disable granted roles, this take affect immediatly, see [SET ROLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10004.htm#SQLRF01704).

Anyway, for your purpose the simplest solution should be this one:

```
create or replace trigger limit_logon 
after logon on database
begin
    if USER = 'USER1' AND to_char(sysdate,'HH24') NOT between 8 and 16 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Logon allowed only from 8 to 16');
    END IF;
    if USER = 'USER2' AND to_char(sysdate,'HH24') NOT between 15 and 23 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Logon allowed only from 15 to 23');
    END IF;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Oracle Virtual Private Database hooked up to the Axiomatics Data Access Filter (disclaimer - I work for Axiomatics). In the Data Access Filter, you can define access control policies that are time-based and also include other parameters such as user or data attributes.

That's the cleanest and most sustainable way.